# In my Blazor server app I have a scoped service that should set lots a variables to their set values. But not working as expected. Why?

Tags: c#, service, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor server app I have a scoped service that should set lots a variables to their set values. This service can be executed from 8 different razor pages. The variables that are set in the service, are visualised  in this razor pages.

I have injected the service to all off the razor pages. But when the service is executed from a razor page, the related variables on the razor page don't get this new values. What is missing?

Update-1********************************************

One of my Razor page

```
@page "/razor_page1"
@using WebApplication7.Pages
@using WebApplication7.Services
@inject TagService TagService
@inject SetTags SetTags

<td >
  <button class="button_1" @onclick="func_button"></button>
</td>

<l>@TagService.Tag1</l>
<l>@TagService.Tag2</l>
<l>@TagService.Tag3</l>

@code {

//on click of a button the service is called but Tag1 & Tag2 don'tchange
public void func_button
 {
  SetTags.Set_Values()  
  }
}
```

My Scoped service for setting values

```
namespace WebApplication7.Services
{

 public class SetTags
  {
   [Inject]
   TagService TagService { get; set; }

   public void Set_Values()
    {
      TagService.Tag1= 32;
      TagService.Tag2= 24;
      TagService.Tag2= 20;
      // lots of other tags to be set.
    }
  }
}
```

My Scoped service for common used Tags

```
namespace WebApplication7.Services
{

 public class TagService
  {
    public int Tag1 { get; set; }=0;
    public int Tag2 { get; set; }=0;
    public int Tag2 { get; set; }=0;
    // all the common variables defined in TagService
    // no function in TagService        
  }
}
```

My Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<ConnectService>();
        services.AddScoped<TagService>();
        services.AddScoped<SetTags>();
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of `SetTags` service ? Seems to me that `TagService` should be the one modifying its own properties. Can you share the code where you inject `TagService` in `SetTags` ? We miss some information to have the full picture, this is why you should provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine  I have updated my code. The TagService is the service where the common variables are defined.

Comment: You can't use [Inject] in services: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-di-in-services)

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine  Sorry didn't get you. Why? The rest of my code and functions are working in this way. I mean I have also other services that uses tags of TagService and have an inject inside there cs .What should I use instead?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine  OK just seen your doc, will look in it

Comment: Use a constructor for the service as it is explained in the link of the doc I provided. As of why, I cannot say for sure but I am going to trust the official Doc on this.